# How can I pass parameters to a jar, whilst using a ClassLoader?

Tags: java, urlclassloader

Here's my code

```
package serverloader;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class ServerLoader {

    public void initiate(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Initiating...");
        URL link = new URL("link");
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{link});
        Object o = classLoader.loadClass("class.MyClass").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Loaded, starting...");
    }

}
```

This is the loader to load my actual application, but for some reason it's not starting up and I believe it's because there are parameters that are needed to launch the application that's being loaded here, so how do I pass the parameters, which are here

```
String[] arguments
```

to the jar that is being loaded by the ClassLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of, you need to use reflection to get the constructor which meets your needs, something like...

```
Class[] clazz = classLoader.loadClass("class.MyClass");
Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String[].class);
```

Once you have the constructor, you can create a new instance of the class using `Constructor#newInstance`...

```
Object o = constructor.newInstance(arguments);
```

As an example...